# Android Kotlin - Asking Permission in RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions, android-context

This is the code inside the Recyclerview Adapter:

```
fun DownloadImage(ImageUrl: String?) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            context,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            context,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            context, // HERE
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
            123
        )
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            context, // AND HERE
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
            123
        )
        Functions(context).showToats(context,"Need Permission to access storage for Downloading Image")
    } else {
        Functions(context).showToats(context,"Downloading Image...")
        //Asynctask to create a thread to downlaod image in the background

        DownloadsImage(context).execute(ImageUrl)
    }
}
```

I get the error: `Type mismatch: inferred type is Context but Activity was expected` where I have commented it.

How to do this right?

getActivity() isn't working too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `getActivity()` will not work because `Recyclerview.Adapter` is not a `fragment`. 
To get the reference to the current `activity`, try passing it to the constructor of the `adapter`.

For example, (in kotlin)

```
class YourAdapter(val yourActivity : AppCompatActivity) : RecyclerView.Adapter<YourViewHolder>()
```

Then use it as

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            yourActivity, // HERE
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
            123
        )
```